# how to initialize struct and call from function to display in main

Tags: c, data-structures

I suppose to create a struct and initialize them in InitiateA and print in DisplayA and call them in Main. I tried to do it, but nothing seems to work?

```
#include <string.h>

struct Penalty{
  // Provide structure definition for Penalty here
  double fine;
  char Identity[20];
  int i;
};

void InitiateA (struct Penalty data[]);
void DisplayA (struct Penalty data[]);

int main(){

  struct Penalty rule[3];
  struct i;

  DisplayA(rule);

  rule[0].fine = 20.00;
  strcpy(rule[0].Identity, "Student" );

  rule[1].fine = 30.00;
  strcpy(rule[1].Identity , "Staff");

  rule[2].fine = 50.00;
  strcpy(rule[2].Identity , "Vendor");

  for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    printf("%d%s",rule[i].fine,rule[i].Identity);
  }   

  return 0;
}
```

i'm not sure on how to call this function to the main function

```
void InitiateA (struct Penalty data[]){
  //intialize data here.
  printf("identity\n");
  printf("%d",rule[i].Identity);
  return;
}

void DisplayA (struct Penalty data[]){
  //display data here
  printf("Fine : RM %d\n", data[i].fine);
  return;
}
```

Did i do it wrongly.?

Comment: Don't write a return statement inside a void function.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error, in `InitiateA()`:

```
printf("%d",rule[i].Identity);
```

You meant

```
printf("%d", data[i].Identity);
```

You can't reference the variable `rule`, it's not in scope at that point (it's a local in `main()`).

You need to call it like this, from `main()`:

```
InitiateA(rule);
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to complete it guys!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct Penalty{

double fine;
char Identity[20];
};

void InitiateA (struct Penalty data[]);
void DisplayA (struct Penalty data[]);


int main(){

struct Penalty rule[3];

InitiateA(rule);
DisplayA(rule);

system ("pause");

}

void InitiateA (struct Penalty data[]){
  data[0].fine = 20.00;
strcpy(data[0].Identity, "Student" );

data[1].fine = 30.00;
 strcpy(data[1].Identity , "Staff");

 data[2].fine = 50.00;
strcpy(data[2].Identity , "Vendor");

}

 void DisplayA (struct Penalty data[]){
  int i;
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
 printf("%s %.2f \n",data[i].Identity, data[i].fine);
}
}
```